# How to extract an array from an object with property and array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object which always have a property and an array. When I print it out with `console.log(obj)`. It likes the following.

```
 ProjectName: MyTest1
 [0] { foo: 1, bar: 2}
 [1] { foo: 3, bar: 4}
 [2] { foo: 5, bar: 6}
```

Or

```
ProjectName: MyTest2
[0] { foo: 1, bar: 2}
[1] { foo: 3, bar: 4}
[2] { foo: 5, bar: 6} 
[3] { foo: 6, bar: 7}
```

**UPDATE**

There are hundreds of them from backend, so the array's size is not fixed. But the object is always a single property plus an array.
This object is a combination of a json object and an array. I want a code to extract it.
Now I want extract the array from the object and assign it to an array variable so I can loop through it. Which means I must get rid of the first property.

**UPDATE1**

I want the new object is extracted from the original object by code rather than hard code since we have many dynamic size array.

```
 [0] { foo: 1, bar: 2}
 [1] { foo: 3, bar: 4}
 [2] { foo: 5, bar: 6}
```

Comment: What array are you trying to get?

Comment: How does your object look like ?

Comment: @NickParsons, I want to get the array which contains `[0].[1],[2]`, The original object combined a property and an array. I don't want the property `ProjectName`

Comment: see here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my comment for "already asked"

for short :

```
var mm=[ 
  { foo: 1, bar: 2} , { foo: 3, bar: 4} ,  { foo: 5, bar: 6} , { foo: 6, bar: 7}
 ];
 mm.property="Hello world";
 console.log("\n1) IsArray ?------------");
 console.log( mm instanceof Array ? "Array":"Other...");
 console.log("2) see mm");
 console.log(mm);

 
 console.log("\nA------- all properties ---------");
 for (var i in mm) {
  if(mm.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
  console.log("property "+i+"=",mm[i]);
  }
 }
 
 
 console.log("\nB------ Array indexes ----------");
 for (var i=0; i<mm.length;i++) {
   console.log("property "+i+"=",mm[i]);
 }
 
 var mm2=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mm));
 mm2[9]="index 10???";
 console.log("\nC------ Array indexes ----------");
 for (var i=0; i<mm2.length;i++) {
   console.log("property "+i+"=",mm2[i]);
 }
```

output :

[image: console output]

## Advice

Avoid mixing properties and array indexes, use a supplementary property to store your array.

```
let myDatas={
 datas : [{xx:yy},{zz:ff}],
 title : "xxxx"
};
```

Comment: Te property is unique. So maybe the best way to do it is to create a dictionary, the key is the property value. Actually the data from the back end is a dictionary. However I have not done the dictionary in typescript yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
let superArray: [] = [];

const obj = {
     a: [{ foo: 1, bar: 2}],
     b: [{ foo: 3, bar: 4}],
     c: [{ foo: 5, bar: 6}] 
};

for (var array in obj) {
    superArray = superArray.concat(obj[array]);
}

console.log(superArray);
```

Comment: It is not related to my question. I wish you understood the question.

Comment: are you trying to assign the first property of the object to a variable array? and have only two properties left in the object?

Comment: Not assign by hard code, see my update., I want to extract it. Because the array could contain 3 elements or more, it is dynamic.